# Hide urls when hovering above <a> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use the below code to hide the URLs when hovering over `<a>` tag links. Below it is set to a certain `<a>` tag (#no-link), I want it to apply to all `<a>` tags. Can anyone help please?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
        $('a[href]#no-link').each(function () {
            var href = this.href;

            $(this).removeAttr('href').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function () {
                if (href.toLowerCase().indexOf("#") >= 0) {

                } else {
                    window.open(href, '_blank');
                }
            });
        });
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: What is the actual purpose of this? Because it's still trivial to find the actual URL. You're only hurting usability, at best.

Comment: I have a lot of photos in page that link to another page. When scrolling it looks messy when the urls keep popping up.

Comment: Also, why is there an `each` if the element you are targeting is described as an `id`: `$('a[href]#no-link')` ('an a element with href attribute and id no-link')?

Comment: Is this the tiny bottom corner url in browsers like chrome? If not, where does this even appear?...

Comment: Can you show up your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, now you are selecting all anchor elements.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 setTimeout(function () {

    $('a').each(function () {
        var href = this.href;

        $(this).removeAttr('href').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function () {
            if (href.toLowerCase().indexOf("#") >= 0) {

            } else {
                window.open(href, '_blank');
            }
        });
    });

}, 500);
});
```

Comment: Not the question that was asked though. An issue, but not _the_ issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this answer,i simply try to hide anchor tags when it hovers

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <a class="no-link" href="samp1.html">samp1</a>
    <a class="no-link" href="samp2.html">samp2</a>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.no-link').hover(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    })

    });
    </script>
```